# Two tables align in different ways with the same stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, forms, html-table

I have two tables. One is created with html (and a little bit of php) while the other is created by two php-loops.

First of all, the stylesheet:

```
.statistics {
    font-family: Arial, monospace;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
}

.statistics tr {
    line-height: 50px;
}

.statistics th {
    text-align: center;
}

.statistics td {
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    margin-left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

The following table is aligned properly:

```
<table class="statistics">
        <tr>
            <th>Benutzer</th>
            <th>Artikel</th>
            <th>Reservierungen</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $client->statistic_getAmount();?></td>
            <td><?php echo $articles->statistic_getAmount();?></td>
            <td><?php echo $reservations->statistic_getAmount();?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Seiten (.php)</th>
            <th>Datenbankeinträge</th>
            <th>Zeilen mit Code</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>4407+</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

While this one isn't aligned properly:

```
<form method="post" action="webinterface.php" class="perms">
        <table class="statistics">
            <tr>
                <th>Benutzer</th>
                <?php
                foreach ($permgroupa as $group) {
                    echo "<th>".$group."<th>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
            $users = $client->getUsers();

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) :?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
                    <?php foreach ($permgroupa as $group) : ?>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $group;?>-<?php echo $row['username'];?>" <?php if ($perms->hasPermission($row['username'], $group)) {echo "checked";}?>></td>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
    </table><button type="submit" class="btnalter" name="alterrights">Rechte aktualisieren</button></form>
```

[The tables in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eot9r.png)

Does someone know, why they align in different ways?

Answer (score 1):

1 - don't put your table inside a form

2 - the number of columns is not the same for the first and the second table

Comment: 1 - How else am I supposed to put the checkboxes in that grid-scheme?
2 - Both foreach loops in the second table create 2 columns.